# Pass datetime in the webapi post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hi i have a date time as below which i have converted into string but it does not pass through

```
     lastRefreshDateTime1 = "2015-07-09T08:38:49-07:00";
await client.PostAsync($"{_printApiUrl}pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/${"{" + lastRefreshDateTime1 + "}"}", content, cancellationToken);
```

but when i pass test then it works fine like shown below.

```
 lastRefreshDateTime1  = "test";
```

then it passes through. What is that i am doing wrong?

Comment: `but it does not pass through` what do you mean? Do you get error or something?

Comment: No i dont get any error but [Route("api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/{lastRefreshDateTime}")] doesnot get called when only passing datetime

Comment: I suggest you URL encode the datetime value

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: `client.PostAsync($"{_printApiUrl}pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/${"{" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lastRefreshDateTime1) + "}"}", content, cancellationToken);` like that?

Comment: @SelimYıldız No this does not work.

Comment: Your existing code creates a URL like this `http://api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/${2015-07-09T08:38:49-07:00}` which doesn't look right

Comment: @stuartd Ok then how do i pass? It should call [Route("api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/{lastRefreshDateTime}")] but it does not

Comment: Possibly this is because you are using both string interpolation and string concatenation and confusing the two. Should it just be `_printApiUrl + "pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lastRefreshDateTime1)`?

Comment: @stuartd this doesnt work as well

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very helpful. Please show the signature of the route you're calling

Comment: [Route("api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/{lastRefreshDateTime}")]

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.And I could get the datetime string successfully.Could you share more details about your `content` and `cancellationToken` and the api you called?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo:

1.Call api:

```
var lastRefreshDateTime1 = "2015-07-09T08:38:49-07:00";
var client = new HttpClient();                      
await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57646/api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/"+ lastRefreshDateTime1,content,cancellationToken);
```

2.Api：

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/{lastRefreshDateTime}")]
public IActionResult Privacy([FromBody]string data,[FromRoute]DateTime lastRefreshDateTime)
{
    //...
}
```

3.Result:
[image]